# handling anonymous users and authenticated users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have a question that has been bother me. I'm making a review based website.

Anonymous users and logged in users can make reviews

if the user is not logged in when they click submit a review, a dialog will show up that says "signup", "login", or **"skip"**

I'm wondering how to deal with these 2 different types of users.

I think having one `reviews` collection would be a good idea. I have a userId as a field should I add an anonId for anonymous users.

would you do something like this:

Review.find({companyName}).populate([{path : "userId", model : "User"},{path : "anonID", model : "Anon"} ])

Would you make anons collection?

problem might be If I want to display **all** reviews for company name some reviews might not have a "userId" and I might get an error.

I have session collection(connect-mongo) that gets populated by people that visited the site.Can I use that? How would I associate that anonymous user with a review. the sessions collection also contains passport.js users

I think I should mention that I want to keep track of all user like how many times they visited the site.

How many times they clicked a button.

**How to handle these 2 types of users?**

Comment: IMO, you are asking for trouble with anonymous comments/reviews because people can put anything in there (spam, xrated stuff, political rants) and you have no accountability (no account to remove, etc...).  If I were going to do anonymous reviews, I'd create an id for them in my database (probably a sequence of digits) and cookie that id on that browser.  I'd probably use a namespace for the id (such as starting with an underscore) that allows me to know it is anonymous so as to not display it.

Comment: This way every review has an ID associated with it and you can tell which ones are automatically generated anon IDs and which are real user IDs.  Since you cookied it, you have a chance to track the user for future reviews too (if the cookie isn't lost).

Comment: Can I use req.sessionID for the ID you are talking about? because I think that gives me a new ID in the `sessions` collection every time a typical person comes in from a browser for the first time.

Comment: you're saying to create a random id for every review. right? sorry I'm slow.

Comment: Yes.  Some unique value for a user ID, but picked such that your code can tell by looking at the ID if it's automatically created or user crated.  It could be the current clock time plus a random number.  Or some monotonically increasing number.  I just think your code would be a lot simpler if every review was associated with an ID.